# .NET Garbage Collection, C++/CLI interior_ptr, and Thread Safety

Tags: .net, pointers, garbage-collection, thread-safety, c++-cli

So I understand that `interior_ptr<typename>` can be used to operate with arrays of structs exactly as in C♯ using the `fixed` statement, but it doesn't fix the array on the heap and lets garbage collection move it around. That's good as I don't want to impede the garbage collector from working effectively. However, the garbage collector runs on a separate thread, and when it is active all the other threads are stopped while the objects on the heap are compacted.

Supposed I had the following code:

```
interior_ptr<unsigned char> sourceBufferPtr = reinterpret_cast<interior_ptr<unsigned char>>(&sourceBuffer[0]) + sourceOffset;
```

The code should runs like this, for example:

1. `&sourceBuffer[0]` returns the address of the first item in the array: 32.
2. `sourceOffset`: 8.
3. `reinterpret_cast<interior_ptr<unsigned char>>(&sourceBuffer[0])` casts the address to an `interior_ptr<unsigned char>`, which gets added to `sourceOffset`.
4. `sourceBufferPtr` should be equal to…

   - 40 if the garbage collector did not move the array.
   - 24 if the garbage collector moved the array to a location like 16.
   - of 40 if the garbage collector moved the array between steps 3 and 4, so the location of the array would be updated to 16 after step 3, but the result assigned to `sourceBufferPtr` would still be 40.

Am I correct to assume that the garbage collector could stop the thread between steps 3 and 4 and possibly assign the wrong value to `sourceBufferPtr` or does the Common Language Runtime somehow *know* how to ensure the entire statement is atomic/value is correct? What *is* safe to do with `interior_ptr<typename>`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Am I correct to assume that the garbage collector could stop the
>   thread between steps 3 and 4 and possibly assign the wrong value to
>   sourceBufferPtr?

Yes, because your code is incorrect. By using reinterpret_cast *after having obtained an unmaanged pointer to the array element* you are introducing a window of opportunity for the GC to invalidate the pointer. You need to use interior_ptr without interruption like this:

```
interior_ptr<unsigned char> bufferPtr = &sourceBuffer[0];
interior_ptr<unsigned char> sourceBufferPtr = bufferPtr + sourceOffset;
```

In this new code, there are only ever interior_ptr's. Even the temporary on the right-hand-side of the second assignment is an interior_ptr.

Comment: Well, after thinking about the C++/CLI specifications, it would make sense to assign the buffer to `pin_ptr<T> sourceBufferPtr` to keep it pinned, and then perform any arithmetic assigning the results to various `interior_ptr<unsigned char>` variables and finally setting `sourceBufferPtr` to `nullptr` to unpin it. The short span would allow me to ensure that the pointer values stay valid and the likelihood of a garbage collection happening in that short period is nearly nil.

Comment: That would work, but the code I gave is safe already. The compiler makes sure to compile this is a way that does not introduce a race with the GC ever. See the example here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y0fh545k(v=vs.80).aspx Looking at the IL the address-taking operation already returns a "managed pointer".

Comment: Ironically, I find myself pinning the pointers anyway. Using C++/CLI in mixed native/managed mode, I can process a larger volume of data much faster by using intrinsics. Example here: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/vclanguage/thread/50cd191d-583a-4bda-b9c0-1c05c2fd05bf